# How can I find which encryption method was used on these strings?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, encryption, mariadb, password-encryption

I'm in the process of trying to migrate my old database. The software that encrypted these values has been deprecated almost 10 years ago and is no longer supported so the service that they used to offer is no longer available. I have more than 10 years of payment information that I need migrated to my new database.

Here are some examples of strings, all from different records so nothing is being exposed

**16 digit number starting with a 4** - (34 characters)

(*32 characters, /, 10 characters, =*)

```
    R4D6PM4P4l3DwL6ofrpkl7h1vtlAeOsj/AuBHIwafDA=
```

**3 digit number** - 34 characters

*4 characters, /, 1 character, /, 15 characters, ==*

```
    rPxW/V/EHWP4zgqpCzAfbQ==
```

**2 digit month between 01 and 12** - (24 characters)

*22 characters, ==*

```
    dGFK5jEpIngIBmIsfKI8bA==
```

**4 digit year between 2000 and 2030** - (24 characters)

*22 characters, ==*

```
    pCjiowNZrCpjcsQ1NYhi6w==
```

**Seed** - All of the seeds are 8 characters

```
    KDbwisaO
```

It was originally developed with VB.NET and MySQL 5.7 (MariaDB 5.7 specifically) was used as the database. I've tried a number of websites that are supposed to help with decryption as well as the native functions in MySQL but can't get coherent information.

I can enter data into the system to generate new encrypted strings, but the utility to export and decrypt them has been discontinued. My next step will be to decompile the .dll files.

Any leads would be appreciated. There are hundereds and it will take weeks to manually copy everything over through the buggy old software. I have no experience with encryption methods so I don't recgonize the patterns.

Comment: The `=` and `==` make me think base64 encoding, but that does not seem to be all that has been done to the original values

Comment: if you don't have the oriinal code, you can decompile the program and check the part where it encrypts, this will cost much less time that trying to figure out which encryption was used. the original developer could also wrote his own algorithm for that matter,

Comment: *4 characters, /, 1 character, /, 15 characters, ==* - as @RiggsFolly said, probably base64 encoded. The `=` is for padding to come to a length dividable by 4 and the `/` is just a normal part of the base64 character set, there is no special meaning. Base64 is usually used to encode when you would otherwise have unprintable characters, which is norml in encryption. Even if we knew the algorithm, we would not know the key.

Comment: Perhaps what could help is if you show a encrypted and corresponding encrypted value someone might be able to help identify the algorithm but as previously mentioned, without any keys that's really not going to solve your problem alone.  decompiling seems like your best bet

Comment: There are a few clues. Each of the blobs, when base64 decoded, becomes a 16 or 32 byte value. I detected no patterns in the the resulting bytes, so it may well be encrypted. A good guess is that it's a 128-bit block cipher, most likely AES. Based on the fact that the first example had 16 characters and encrypted to 32, it reasonable to guess that PKCS7 padding was used to pad the plaintext. Also, there is no extra data evidencing an initialization vector, so ECB mode is another reasonable guess.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you. THat's helpful. Would do AES or PKCS7 use seeds?

Comment: Given that the whole point of encrypting the data was to prevent what you're basically trying to do now, do you hope that it's easy or hard to decrypt? If it's easy for you then it's easy for anyone and your data was never safe to begin with. Are you unable to use the original software at all?

Comment: If they used a "salt" with the encryption, you are out of luck.

Comment: RE: If I can crack this, is it unsafe?
Not completely. It was always blocked off on a firewalled server and  the encryption was really just to stop piracy back in the the early 2000s.

RE: Salt? I have the seeds, I don't know if there is any relation.